# Why do I need the v-bind when I have the v-on?

Tags: vue.js

In the tutorial of vue.js, we have this code

```
<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      text: ''
    }
  },
  methods: {
    onInput(e) {
      this.text = e.target.value
    }
  }
}
</script>

<template>
  <input :value="text" @input="onInput" placeholder="Type here">
  <p>{{ text }}</p>
</template>
```

And I don't understand why when I delete the bind on value, the two way binding is still working ?
In the tuto, it says that using the v-on & v-bind allow to do two way binding
Am I missing something ?

Answer (score 1):

The Vue example is sort of a bad use case, a little simple for what it's trying to convey:

v-on is for assigning event listeners, so v-on:click="doSomething(value)"

v-bind is binding the actual value of vue data/state. So example:

`<button v-on:click="setUserDetails(value)" v-bind:value="user.id">Click</button>`

Answer (score 1):

Imagine this component:

```js
<template>
  <input :value="value"/>
</template>
<script>
export default {
 name: 'MyComp',
 props:{
  value: String
 }
}
</script>
```

And now a simple usage of it:

```js
<template>
  <MyComp v-model="passwd" type="password" minlength="3" @focus="onFocus"/>
</template>
<script>
export default {
 name: 'MyOtherComp',
 data(){
  return {
   passwd: ''
  }
 },
 methods:{
   onFocus(){}
 }
}
</script>
```

As you can see, `value`, `type`, and `minlength` properties and `focus` event are bidden to `MyComp`.

Now question: How can I handle extra props in `MyComp`? they are not defined in `MyComp` props. Vue gathers them in a special variable called `$attrs`, which is a normal JS object. Vue also gathers all events into `$listeners` variable.
Now inside `MyComp` these special variables are:

```js
$atrrs:{
  type: 'password',
  minlength: '3'
}

$listerners:{
 focus: /* function onFocus from parent */
}
```

To redirect these values:

```js
<template>
 <input :value="value" v-bind="$attrs" v-on="$listeners"/>
</template>

<script>
export default {
 name: 'MyComp',
 props:{
   value: String
 }
}
</script>
```

As you can see, we use `v-bind` to bind extra props, and we use `v-on` to bind (redirect) events. The result is:

```js
 <input :value="value" :type="$attrs.type" :minlength="$attrs.minlength" @focus="$listeners.focus"/>
```

Of course you can use these directions to bind you objects too:

```js
<template>
  <input :value="value" v-bind="$attrs" v-bind="accumulated" v-on="$listeners"/>
</template>
<script>
export default {
 name: 'MyComp',
 props:{
  value: String
 },
 data(){
   return {
    accumulated:{
     maxlenght: (+this.$attrs.minlength || 2) + 30, // It's just for a practice to use extra props inside JS code :-) 
     rows: 5,
    }
   }
 }
}
</script>
```

Keep in mind that duplicate props will replace and the last one wins.